# Marketo "Import Lead" fails with error 610 Requested resource not found

Tags: rest, curl, marketo

I'm trying to batch **update a bunch of existing records** through Marketo's REST API. According [to the documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/import-lead/), the Import Lead function seems to be ideal for this.

In short, I'm getting the error "610 Resource Not Found" upon using the curl sample from the documentation. Here are some steps I've taken.

1. Fetching the auth_token is not a problem:

```
$ curl "https://<identity_path>/identity/oauth/token?
    grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<my_client_id>
    &client_secret=<my_client_secret>"
```

2. Proving the token is valid, fetching a single lead isn't a problem as well:

```
# Fetch the record - outputs just fine
$ curl "https://<rest_path>/rest/v1/lead/1.json?access_token=<access_token>"

# output:
{
  "requestId": "ab9d#12345abc45",
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "updatedAt": "2014-09-18T13:00:00+0000",
      "lastName": "Potter",
      "email": "harry@hogwartz.co.uk",
      "createdAt": "2014-09-18T12:00:00+0000",
      "firstName": "Harry"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

3. Now here's the pain, when I try to upload a CSV file using the [Import Lead function](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/import-lead/). Like so:

```
# "Import Lead" function
$ curl -i -F format=csv -F file=@test.csv -F access_token=<access_token> 
    "https://<rest_path>/rest/bulk/v1/leads.json"

# results in the following error
{
  "requestId": "f2b6#14888a7385a",
  "success": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "610",
      "message": "Requested resource not found"
    }
  ]
}
```

The [error codes documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/error-codes/) only states *Requested resource not found*, nothing else. So my question is: what is causing the 610 error code - and **how can I fix it**?

Further steps I've tried, with no success:

- Placing the access_token as url parameter (e.g. appending '?access_token=xxx' to the url), with no effect.
- Stripping down the CSV (yes, it's comma seperated) to a bare minimum (e.g. only fields 'id' and 'lastName')
- Looked at the question [Marketo API and Python, Post request failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411664/marketo-api-and-python-post-request-failing)
- Verified that the CSV doesn't have some funky line endings
- I have no idea if there are specific requirements for the CSV file, like column orders, though...

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error code 610 can represent something akin to a '404' for urls under the REST endpoint, i.e. your `rest_path`.  I'm guessing this is why you are getting that '404': Marketo's docs show REST paths as starting with '/rest', yet their rest endpoint ends with /rest, so if you follow their directions you get an url like, `xxxx.mktorest.com/rest/rest/v1/lead/...`, i.e. with '/rest' twice. This is not correct. Your url must have only one 'rest/'.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, no - that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm not getting a 404 (in fact, I get a HTTP/1.1 200 OK after handshake) and the error message is provided as a JSON callback from the webservice, as you can see in the third codeblock from my question. It's the Marketo service which spits out the exception.

Comment: I know, I'm saying that if you hit http://xxxx.mktorest.com/rest/some/path/which/doesnt/exist you'll get a 200 OK and a response body with that 'code 610... resource not found' stuff. So it's *like* a 404, but not really a 404. Can you paste in the full, real url you are trying to POST to? (You can omit the access token if you want.) I'm still thinking it has '/rest/rest/' in it, which would give you that code 610.

Comment: It looks like you're right! Using https://AAA.mktorest.com/rest/bulk/v1/" gave the error, but using  "https://AAA.mktorest.com/bulk/v1/" did not. Notice the **entire replacing of /rest/ with /bulk/** in the final path. Although this gives another error, the 610 message has now dissapeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same trouble, just want to share some points that help resolve my problem.

- Bulk API endpoints are not prefixed with ‘/rest’ like other endpoints.
- Bulk Import uses the same permissions model as the Marketo REST API and does not require any additional special permissions in order to use, though specific permissions are required for each set of endpoints.
- As [@Ethan Herdrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25923615/7605967) suggested, the endpoints in the documentation are sometimes prefixed with an extra `/rest`, make sure to remove that.

If you're a beginner and need step-by-step instructions to set up permissions for Marketo REST API: [Quick Start Guide for Marketo REST API](https://developers.marketo.com/blog/quick-start-guide-for-marketo-rest-api/)